# C# - Unable to find confirmed answer for hashset contains comparison check

Tags: c#, hashset, equality

I tried to find out how C# goes about comparing objects in a HashSet for equality.

I couldn't find anything here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx

Only when I came to stackoverflow, I read that it uses the Equals() and *maybe* getHashCode()

I was planning to implement both methods anyways, but my question is:

What would you do to find out how HashSet actually compares objects?

Comment: Worth reading: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx

Comment: I found the documentation slightly confusing as well, so I wrote a simple console app with a class with various combinations of Equals and GetHashCode overrides and/or IEquality<T> implementations, with simple debug statements within each of those. Then I added a collection of the objects to a HashSet and reviewed the debug output to determine what the minimum requirements were for HashSet to work correctly. It helped clear up the intent of the MS documentation. I also ran tests where my class inherited from an IEquatable base class or interface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It compares objects for equality using `Equals`. It determines which bucket to place them in using `GetHashCode`.

More generically, HashSet uses the `IEqualityComparer<T>` passed in to its constructor to do both. If none is specified, it uses `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` which calls the object's `GetHashCode()` and `IEquatable<T>.Equals()` method (or `object.Equals()` if the type doesn't implement `IEquatable<T>`).

Comment: Just experience with how hash tables usually work and how IEqualityComparer<T> is used in .Net. I also verified it using Reflector.

Comment: Reflector, hmm, who'd of thought of doing that ;)

Comment: what's reflector ?  why is msdn doc website to hard to understand ? :)

Comment: A tool for enabling you to look at the code of any un-obfuscated .NET assembly.

Comment: Reflector is a disassembler for .Net. Basically what I told you is an implementation detail; as far as the contract for the class goes, it's basically just "it uses an IEqualityComparer<T> so it should be assumed that both GetHashCode and Equals are required".

Comment: I think after browsing thru the msdn link I understood how your info matches the class description. I truly wish this msdn site was somewhat easier to follow.  Thanks for the help.